# Apply masterPage to SearchCenter on Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2007, master-pages, moss, sharepoint-designer

I am working in a project in `Sharepoint Designer` that was already built in `MOSS 2007`, and it has the structure:

An site collection `/` and some subsites, one of them called `SearchCenter`.

The `SearchCenter` is where the sharepoint is redirected when you make search, but it has the default layout from iternal sites (it have its own masterpage defined in its folder) in sharepoint.
I would like to know how to apply one masterpage from the `catalogs/masterpages` to this subsite.

Answer (score 0):

You get to profit from my pain Tito...

If you try to use the default OOTB teamsite-like masterpage (default.master) on a search template, you get all types of errors.

You need to base your custom masterpage off out minimal.master.  Try not to modify the original minimal.master.  Make a copy of minimal.master, then add your custom HTML, JS, CSS and SharePoint placeholders to the copy.

Afterwards, goto Site Settings, and set your custom minimal.master copy as the custom masterpage for the search center.